# @angular/router is not installed correctly

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-routing

I¡m trying to updgrade my @angular/router dependency from 2.0.0 to 3.0.0-alpha.7

I have added it to package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\"",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-alpha.7",
    ........
  },

}
```

When I use "npm install" router is installed but "bundles" folder is not created.
[image]

So, when I try to run my project I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Someboy knows what could be happening?

Thanks
Iván.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been solved in version alpha-8.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: this can be a comment instead of answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have latest systemjs.config.js file. Below block is added few days back after RC2 release (and before RC3 release)-

```
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
```

Comment: As far as I know the new router by mistake is not yet in the `bundles/` directory as the other modules.

Comment: It says this is fixed but npm installing a fresh copy of "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7" still yields a router folder without a bundles folder.